# Submit form with AJAX after Jquery validation (bvalidator)

Tags: jquery

I know this is a very common (and basic) question, however I've tried without success.

I have a basic form and I'm using [bValidator](http://karmela.fsb.hr/~bmauser/bvalidator/documentation.html) (jQuery):

```
    <form id="contactform" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" data-bvalidator="required" />
    <input type="text" id="courriel" name="courriel"  data-bvalidator="email,required" />
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="4"  data-bvalidator="minlength[20],required"></textarea>
    <input type="image" src="images/send_btn.png" id="sendform" />
    </form>
```

and I'm trying to send the $.ajax() after validation and it just doesn't work...

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#contactform').bValidator();
        });
        $('#sendform').click(function() {
            $.ajax({ (----process.php---!!!!) });
        }
```

I know this is not the right way to do it...

Thaks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [jQuery.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). The docs have examples that guide you further.

Basically, it works like

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  var payload = $(this).serialize();
  // do the ajax request with "data" option set to payload
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is here: [How to integrate jquery.bvalidator and jquery.form plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246992/how-to-integrate-jquery-bvalidator-and-jquery-form-plugins/6300702#6300702). Use bValidator with jQuery Form Plugin.