# How to integrate jquery.bvalidator and jquery.form plugins?

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I'm trying to use these plugins to validate ([bValidator](http://code.google.com/p/bvalidator/)) and submit my form ([Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)), without success:

```
    var myvalidator = $('#contForm').bValidator();
    if(myvalidator.isValid()) {
    $('#contForm').ajaxSubmit(function() { 
            alert("Thank you for your message!"); 
            return false;
    });
    }
```

The validation part is ok, however the ajaxSubmit is not working...

Thanks in advance for your help!    `

Comment: what error message are you getting? try using firebug.

Comment: there is no error message so far... the ajax is not working (it goes to the process.php file as if there was no ajax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is:

```
$('#contForm').bValidator();

$('#contForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
    alert("Thank you for your message!");
});
```

.bValidator() must be called before .ajaxForm() to stop form submit if validation fails.

You can also do like this:

```
var myvalidator = $('#contForm').bValidator();

$('#contForm').submit(function(){
    if(myvalidator.isValid()){
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(function() { 
            alert("Thank you for your message!");
        }); 
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myvalidator = $('#myForm').bValidator();

$('#myForm').submit(function()
{
    //call ajax here
    ....

    //disable submit post
    return false;
});
```